# Auto dismiss keyboard when change controller Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uikeyboard

In this case I can do a dismiss keyboard when I tap everywhere after done editing. However my keyboard stuck and can't hide automatically if I don't tap everywhere. 
Example : When I done edit a textField, I don't tap anywhere to dismiss the keyboard but I tap next button, and the keyboard still showed up in the next page. 
Question : How to auto dismiss keyboard when I target to another controller.

Code below is a normal tap to dismiss keyboard.

```
let dismiss: UITapGestureRecognizer =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
mainView.addGestureRecognizer(dismiss)
---------------------------
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**ADDITIONAL**

here is my code to get another controller

```
//Implement UITextFieldDelegate
extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterMpinViewController") as! EnterMpinViewController
        secondViewController.pinProtocol = self
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        //        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entermPINController", sender: self)
    }
}
```

so if I tap the textField I jump into another controller to add the pin. and the keyboard is stuck there.

Extension Code :

```
//Implement viewWillDisappear
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code of the `hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround` method?. You've added two ways to hide the keyboard when user touch on the textfield, but I think we just need `self.view.endEditing(true)` is enough

Comment: Oh it's the same with before. The different is I only make this to extension `UIViewController`. inside of the code still the same I use this one `self.view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `BaseViewControler`, which is sub-class of `UIViewController`. Then you override `viewWillDisappear` method, and hide the keyboard there.
And every `view controller` should be sub-class of this `BaseViewController`.

Comment: Same with the way you use to hide keyboard: `self.view.endEditing(true)`

Comment: still can't sir. the kebyoard still stuck there

Comment: You know how to debug, right? Put a breakpoint on that line in the `viewWillDisappear` and see if it's hit.

Comment: yes the `viewWillDisappear` hit, but the keyboard not dismissed

Comment: ok so the `viewWillDisappear` hit, case 1 : after done editing I tap everywhere in the view, and the keyboard disappear.
Case 2 : after done editing (without tap anywhere in the view) I tap button to access other controller. in this part my keyboard doesn't dismissed. 
Both case hit the `viewWillDisappear` func . I debug and checked it already

Comment: Impossible, I just tested with my code. It works properly.

Answer (score -1):

Write like Below Code:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```